# Unity Buttons Assignment

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm pretty new to C# and Unity, so sorry if my question is too simple.
I'm trying to create an easy Upgrade System made from text and button for each stat.
I made the Text script to show my "Attack Damage" stat, which worked. Now, I want to create a script Button so once that I click it my stat will go from (ex. 10 to 11) or anything. So my question is: how can I access variables from another script so that i can use them to be incremented by clicking the button?
I'll attach both the scripts, please try to explain as simple as you can, so that a newbie can understand. Thanks!

Attack Damage Text Script ( Keep in mind that in Player class the heroDamage is set to 10f)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class AttackDamage : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static float attackDamage = Player.heroDamage;

    public Text attackDamageText;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        attackDamageText.text = ADButton.attack.ToString(); //here it was attackDamage.ToString() at first but i wanted to see if it works like that.
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

Attack Damage Button Script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ADButton : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Button attackDamageButton;

    public static float attack;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        attackDamageButton.onClick.AddListener(Update);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        attack = AttackDamage.attackDamage;
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            attack++;
    }
}
```

I guess my second code is wrong, but I don't know how can I modify it.

Answer (score 0):

https://answers.unity.com/questions/1336162/how-to-reference-a-class-in-another-script-properl.html

This shows various possible methods.
But the simpler is reference by object.

like

```
public class AttackDamage : MonoBehaviour 
{
        // Start is called before the first frame update
        void Start()
        {

        }


        public void Method1()
        {
          // Do Something like Attack++;
        } 
}

public class ADButton : MonoBehaviour 
{           
        public AttackDamage obj;

        // Start is called before the first frame update
        void Start()
        {
          obj.Method1();
        }


}
```

Also in this case you need to assign the class `AttackDamage` in inspector on GameObject having `ADButton` script.